# Boundary of $x^2+x$ Julia set

Tags: dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

How do you calculate an infinite fixed point for $f=x^2+x$, so that $f^{o n}(x)$ never repeats, and doesn't go to infinity and doesn't go to zero?  Can such a sequence of points densely cover the entire Cauliflower Julia set boundary?  I may have discovered approximations for such points sort of accidentally, but I don't know much about it.  Also, any references?

Comment: How is it possible to never repeat , not go to 0 and not go to infinity ? You mean a limit cycle ?

Comment: @mick, an infinite fixed point cycle.... otherwise it wouldn't densely cover the boundary of the cauliflower.  An approximation for such a number: -0.86805350289426250593637022087715 + 1.0327822503323875673886840036798*I.  I ran across it trying to solve [another post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208996/half-iterate-of-x2c) I made on stack exchange, looking for references.  I'll look up Milnor's book when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(By the way, I prefer $z\mapsto z^2+\frac14$ over $z\mapsto z^2+z$ for aestetical reasons.)

As long as the Julia set $J$ is connected, there is a holomorphic map  $\phi$ of the exterior of the Julia set to the exterior of the unit disc and such that $\phi(z^2+z)=\phi(z)^2$. For any irrational angle $e^{i\alpha}$, $\frac\alpha\pi\notin \mathbb Q$, the orbit of $e^{i\alpha}$ under squaring is dense in $S^1$. Provided that $z_0=\lim_{r\to1^+}\phi^{-1}(re^{i\alpha})$ exists, I'd expect that the orbit of $z_0$ under $z\mapsto z^2+z$ is dense in $\partial J$.

---

**Edit:** Actually I jumped too short when I first wrote this up - I was thinking of the density of $n\alpha\bmod 2\pi$ instead of $2^n\alpha\bmod 2\pi$. Thus $\frac\alpha{2\pi}$ should not just be irrational; rather it should be a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) in base 2.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out on the way home.  I've also decided that sometimes z^+1/4 is better, and sometimes z^2+z is better, depending on the problem.  For this problem, I definitely agree z^2+1/4 is better.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but note that for all external rays to land you need local connectivity of the Julia set (which is not always the case, though for $z^2+1/4$ it is). you can work around this since a positive measure set of angles will land, and normal numbers have full Lebesgue measure. but this is overkill: it's simpler to use the fact that $f: J \to J$ is topologically transitive, as can be proved using Montel's theorem. it is classical that transitivity is equivalent to the existence of a dense orbit