# Solve the function from the composition

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

I have equations as follows
$$f(f(x))=x^2+x$$
Then solve for $f(x)$.
Can anyone give some hints about this question?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of a very recent question.

Comment: On what set is it supposed to be true?

Comment: Gotcha! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-get-fx-if-we-know-ffx-x2x

Comment: Probably homework from a class if it was asked twice in two days.

Comment: Three times, actually. There is another question from yesterday that was closed as  a duplicate as well.

Comment: I saw this question from websites and tried to solve it, but I failed. So I come here to ask for help.

Comment: @sdg Out of curiosity, which website?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut I don't remember what the website is exactly. But one of my friends also asked me the same question yesterday. He said he saw that from a website, too. But he didn't tell me which it was.