# Limit involving tetration

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponential-function, tetration

Let the notation be $a^{\wedge\wedge}b 
= \underbrace{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{a}}}}}_{b\,times}$ for tetration.

My mentor conjectured the following:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, then let $A(n)$ be any function that satisfies
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(e^{\frac1e} +
> \frac1n\right)^{\wedge\wedge}\left[(10 n)^{1/2} + n^{A(n)} + C+o(1)\right] - n = 0$$
>
> where $C $ is a constant. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A(n) = \frac1e $

Conjectured by
tommy1729
Here : 
http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=262&page=4

So could this be true ?

I have no idea how to do limits like this. I assume these type of limits are not in the books.

Comment: What's that $A(n)$?

Comment: A(n) is just the function that makes the equation valid.

Comment: Also, I believe that $C+o(1)=o(1)=c$ is a constant, so it is a little unnecessary.

Comment: No no o(1) is depending on n and between 1 and 0. C is an  independent value.

Comment: How do you define $a^{\wedge\wedge}b$ for non-integer $b$?

Comment: $a^{\wedge\wedge}b$ is not defined for non-integers. I think the $o(1)$ is intended to account for this. It might be better wrapped in a ceiling function if this is the case, as he says that $0 \leq o(1) \leq 1$.

Comment: That would be a good idea, it would fix ambiguity regarding this

Comment: o(1) is An error term. Not to be confused with big O.

Comment: I love that there is a "Tetration Forum"! Is it known that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(e^{\frac1e} +
\frac1n\right)^{\wedge\wedge}\left[(10 n)^{1/2} + n^{1/e} + C+o(1)\right] - n = 0$ ?

Comment: For any particular $C$?

Comment: I don't think that the limit given can be equal to zero. $e^{\frac{1}{e}} > 1$, and tetration definitely has greater than linear growth.

Comment: The o(1) is a weaker statement then a ceiling. Non-Unique ways of noninteger  iterations are bridged by this o(1).

Comment: At cuddly : your wrong exp(1/e)^^oo = e !!

Comment: You have $(e^{1/e}+1/n)>1.4$ and $[(10n)^{1/2}+n^{A(n)}+C+o(1)]>n^{1/2}$ for $n$ big enough.
But  lim(1.4^^(n^{1/2})-n)=lim (1.4^^n-n^2)$=+\infty$ ???

Comment: See my response to Tommy's question.  I believe the "correct" $\sqrt{10n}$ term would be 
$$2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\exp(1/e)\cdot n}{2e}}\approx\sqrt{10.4907n} $$ 
http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=262&page=4
But I can't prove it, so this is a comment; not an answer.  The middle term in the Op's question, $n^{1/e}$ seems completely incorrect however,  Numerically, with the Op's equation, C gets arbitrarily large as n grows bigger than 10^9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct formula, where $\eta=\exp(1/e)$ and $\alpha(x)$ is the upper repelling fixed point Abel function for iterating $x \mapsto \exp(x)-1$, which is generated using Ecalle's fps solution.  For details, see posts by Will Jagy on $\alpha(x)$: [How to obtain $f(x)$, if it is known that $f(f(x))=x^2+x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-obtain-fx-if-it-is-known-that-ffx-x2x)

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \text{sexp}_{(\eta+1/n)}\left[\pi\sqrt{\frac{2\eta\cdot n}{e}} -2\right] \approx 388.7874$$
I obtained the above limit value numerically, and then used that result to generate a corrected equation for the Op's question.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \text{sexp}_{(\eta+1/n)}\left[\pi\sqrt{\frac{2\eta\cdot n}{e}} + \alpha(\frac{n}{e}-1) + C\right] -n = 0$$
$$C \approx -2 - \alpha(\frac{388.7874}{e}-1)$$

I was about to post a closely related question about Pi in the Mandelbrot set; it takes about $\pi \sqrt{n}$ iterations to escape near the parabolic cusp at c=0.25+1/n.  Then I found this paper about the occurrence of Pi in the Mandelbrot set; although I haven't finished reading their paper, but presumably the same linear differential equation mechanisms can be used to justify the result, that it takes $\pi \sqrt{2n}$ iterations to "escape" for iterating $x \mapsto \exp(x)-1+\frac1n$, where we start at $x=-1+\frac1n$.  Both iterations involve perturbations of $\frac1n$ near a parabolic fixed point.

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jb/teaching/jmc/pi-in-mandelbrot.pdf
https://people.math.osu.edu/edgar.2/piand.html

It is simpler and mathematically equivalent to work with iterating $f(x)=\exp(x)-1+\frac1n$.  Using the paper's methods, then one would want to prove it takes $\pi\sqrt{2n}$ iterations, for the function to begin growing, where growth would be defined as $f^{\circ \pi\sqrt{2n}}>2$; after that growth is superexponential.

n for iterating $f(x)=\exp(x)-1+\frac1n$ is equivalent to $n=\ln(\ln(\eta+1/m))+1\approx \frac{e}{\eta\cdot m} + \frac{\mathcal{O}}{m^2}$ for iterating $g(x) =(\eta+1/m)^x$  Then there is a simple linear conversion $f^{\circ k} = \frac{g^{\circ k}}{e}-1$  That is why I used $\alpha(\frac{n}{e}-1)$  in my corrected solution equation for the Op's question.

Comment: Also, notice that $\pi\sqrt{\frac{2\eta\cdot n}{e}} \approx \sqrt{10.49n}$, so this is close to the Op's original $\sqrt{10n}$ term.