# Is it possible to find aproximation of conformal map from sequences of complex points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, functional-equations, conformal-geometry, complex-dynamics

I want to find equation of conformal map (= [Fatou function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation) $\Psi : z \to u$ )  which:

- maps some region of complex plane ( attracting petal) to right half of complex plane in u coordinate $Re(u) > 0 $
- transforms function $f(z)$   to unit translation $ F : u \to u+1$
- unrolls invariant curvs ( orbits ) : maps  "circles" to straight lines

Can I find equation which aproximates such map from sequences of points ( complex numbers) ?

The easiest case is $f(z)= z^2 + z$ which has parabolic fixed point at origin ( z=0). 
Then $\Psi(z) = -1/z$  and $F : u \to u+1+1/(u-1)$, where $2/(u-1)$ is error term ( Adrien Douady, Does a Julia set depend continuously on the polynomial? )

Sequences lay along curves shown inside [main chessboard boxe](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/pcheckerboard) on this image[image: Sequences lay along curves shown on this image] The image is not perfect near boundaries of chessboard box ( there are kinks and curves seems to cross boundary )

On this image one can see the u and z planes for th case f(z)=z^2+z. [Src code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Domains_for_Fatou_coordinate_for_f(z)_%3D_z%2Ba_2z_%5E2%2BO(z%5E3).png)
[image]

Comment: This common point is a fixed point of f(z). The split looks better.

Comment: Yes : "The first step in constructing Fatou coordinate for f0 consists in lifting f0 to a neighborhood of infinity by the coordinate change  z→ −1/(qz^q)." http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5536.  I do not know how to do next steps. I can compute sequences z, f(z), ... easly. Can I ( and how) use it to find more precise aproximation ?

Comment: Can you describe what you have done as an answer ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge/

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-obtain-fx-if-it-is-known-that-ffx-x2x/

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods for [numerically approximating conformal maps from arbitrary domains to the unit disc](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52106179.pdf):

- [the SchwarzChristoffel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping)
- the geodesic algorithm
- the circle packing method

Comment: `zipper` is a software implementation, I used the FORTRAN version once https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2013-08-17_elpis.html

Comment: https://github.com/johncbowers/koebepy