# Easy looking functional equation.

Tags: functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Find all functions that satisfy $$ f (f (x))=x^2-3x+4$$
Any thoughts and approachs to find $f (x)$ ?

Comment: Its not a polinomial i guess, but it may be an exponential. I can't think of anything else. A friend of mine asked this to me.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I think that $f(n)=f(3-n) $ certainly for the first few integers. Perhaps progress can be made thinking about transformations?

Answer (score 3):

There is an $f$ that is $C^\infty$ for $x > 3/2.$ It is real analytic for $x \neq 2.$ You can get $C^1$ on the whole line by reflecting across $x = 3/2.$

The method is difficult, see similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208996/half-iterate-of-x2c/209653#209653 for $x^2 + x.$ This version seems more complete [How to obtain $f(x)$, if it is known that $f(f(x))=x^2+x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-obtain-fx-if-it-is-known-that-ffx-x2x/912324#912324)   My best answer on this stuff is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/46765#46765  on $f(f(x)) = \sin x,$ and Gottfried posted a lovely picture of the resulting $f.$

We know that we need to use the intricate Ecalle method because the function has a fixed point at $x=2,$ with slope equal to one there. The curve is tangent to the line $y=x,$ which rules out easier methods.

[image]