# How to obtain $f(x)$, if it is known that $f(f(x))=x^3+x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> How to get $f(x)$, if we know that $f(f(x))=x^3+x$? Is there an elementary function $f(x)$ that satisfies the equation?

**Reference:** [How to obtain $f(x)$, if it is known that $f(f(x))=x^2+x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-obtain-fx-if-it-is-known-that-ffx-x2x)

***Note***: **Will Jagy gave a superb approximation of $f(f(x))$** in this reference above, that is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVD6p.png) even for large x>10.

Now, how do we derive $f(x)$ in $f(f(x))$ which give good approximation using the same method for x>10?

Answer (score 1):

It's messier for large $x$, but still the first couple of terms are gettable.
The first term is $x^{\sqrt3}$ of course.
Next  try $x^{\sqrt3}+\alpha(x)+\ldots$.  Then
$$f(f(x))=f\left(x^{\sqrt3}(1+\frac{\alpha(x)}{x^{\sqrt3}}+\ldots)\right)\\
=x^3(1+\sqrt3 \frac{\alpha(x)}{x^{\sqrt3}}+\ldots) +\alpha(x^{\sqrt3})+\ldots$$
Pick an $\alpha(x)$ so the leading correction term is $1x^1$.  You can then introduce a $\beta(x)$ that will remove the next-largest correction term, and so on.

Comment: Hi sir, Great answer!!!  Can you provide a working series for x=5? It's awesome to see it working and the derivation of it. Sorry if it takes time.

Comment: No, your turn ${}$