# Find $f$ if $f(f(x))=ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: quadratics, functional-equations

For polynomials with powers 1 and under, it's easy to find the [functional square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root).

i.e. if:
$$f(f(x)) = f^{[2]}(x) = ax+b$$

then:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}+1}$$

Is it possible to find a general form for a quadratic function? I.e what is $f$, given that $$f^{[2]}(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Comment: You could try assuming $g$ has a Taylor Series expansion, and then see what conditions you get on the coefficients in order for $g \circ g$ to equal f.

Comment: See [Find $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x)) = x^2 - 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481017/find-fx-such-that-ffx-x2-2). Note in particular that the answer depends on what the domain requirements are for $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to such equations in general. For example, there is no solution to $f(f(x)) = x^2 - 2$ - see problem 7 [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0).

However, some of those equations do have a nontrivial solution, for example $f(f(x)) = x^2 +2$. Can you find one?