# Existance of a function satisfying given equation

Tags: real-analysis

Examine the existence of a function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that:

$\forall x \in \mathbb R\ :f(f(x))= x^2 +1$

How to approach this type of problems? 
I study functional equation from a book of B.J.Venkatachala but I don't know how to approach problems having a composition of functions. Need help.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/If-f-f-x-x-2-1-what-is-f-x

Comment: A small bait-and-switch: Like all logistic maps, this one is solved numerically through  Schröder's equation. However, there is a concise closed solution for $f(f(x))=x^2-2$, instead, invented by him in 1870: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2305794/362193).

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting problem. [This paper](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/rice-when.pdf) discusses the problem at length and contains a strong result that implies, in particular, the following:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x)=ax^2+(b+1)x+c$ and let $\Delta(g)=b^2-4ac$. Then for each positive integer $n$, a solution $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to $f^n=g$ exists if and only if $\Delta(g)\leq 1$.

In your case, we have $g(x)=x^2+1$, so $\Delta(g)=1-4=-3$, and hence existence is guaranteed.

---

Further interesting readings on the topic might include [Schröder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation), or [this paper](https://www.scientificbulletin.upb.ro/rev_docs_arhiva/full24166.pdf) on solutions of $f^2=g$ for $g$ that fail to be injective.